# Angular svg or canvas to use colour gradients

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, d3.js, svg

I am using angular and d3 to create a donut (in a directive).

I can quite simply give the filled area a colour (in this plunker it is blue). But what i want to do is have the SVG change its colours smoothly from:

```
0% - 33.3% - red
33.4% - 66.66% - orange
66.7% - 100% green
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('donutDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            radius: '=',
            percent: '=',
            text: '=',
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var radius = scope.radius,
                percent = scope.percent,
                percentLabel = scope.text,
                format = d3.format(".0%"),
                progress = 0;

            var svg = d3.select(element[0])
                .append('svg')
                .style('width', radius/2+'px')
                .style('height', radius/2+'px');

            var donutScale = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, 100])
                .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

            //var color = "#5599aa";
            var color = "#018BBB";

            var data = [
                [0,100,"#b8b5b8"],
                [0,0,color]
            ];

            var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                .innerRadius(radius/6)
                .outerRadius(radius/4)
                .startAngle(function(d){return donutScale(d[0]);})
                .endAngle(function(d){return donutScale(d[1]);});

            var text = svg.append("text")
                .attr("x",radius/4)
                .attr("y",radius/4)
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("font-size","14px")
                .style("fill","black")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text(percentLabel);

            var path = svg.selectAll("path")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("path")
                .style("fill", function(d){return d[2];})
                .attr("d", arc)
                .each(function(d) {
                    this._current = d;
                    // console.log(this._current)
                ;});

            // update the data!
            data = [
                [0,100,"#b8b5b8"],
                [0,percent,color]
            ];

            path
                .data(data)
                .attr("transform", "translate("+radius/4+","+radius/4+")")
                .transition(200).duration(2150).ease('linear')
                .attrTween("d", function (a) {
                    var i  = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
                    var i2 = d3.interpolate(progress, percent)
                    this._current = i(0);
                    // console.log(this._current);
                    return function(t) {
                        text.text( format(i2(t) / 100) );
                        return arc(i(t));
                    };
                });
        }
    };
});
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/8qGMeQkmM08CZxZIVRei?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i want to do is have the SVG change its colours smoothly from:
>
> ```
> 0% - 33.3% - red
> 33.4% - 66.66% - orange
> 66.7% - 100% green
> ```

Assuming that you want a color transition/scale like this one:

[image]

See working code for this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLVmyV

You can smothly make the color transition using a d3 linear scale like this:

```
//Create a color Scale to smothly change the color of the donut
var colorScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,33.3,66.66,100]).range(['#cc0000','#ffa500','#ffa500','#00cc00']);
```

Then, when you update the path (with the attrTween) to make the filling animation, take only the Path the represents the filled part of the donut, lets call it **colorPath** and change the fill of it adding the following like in the tween:

```
//Set the color to the path depending on its percentage
//using the colorScale we just created before
colorPath.style('fill',colorScale(i2(t)))
```

Your attrTween will look like this:

```
colorPath.data([[0,percent,color]])
.transition(200).duration(2150).ease('linear')
.attrTween("d", function (a) {
    var i  = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
    var i2 = d3.interpolate(progress, percent)
    this._current = i(0);
    // console.log(this._current);
    return function(t) {
        text.text( format(i2(t) / 100) );
        colorPath.style('fill',colorScale(i2(t)))
        return arc(i(t));
    };
});
```

Please note that we only update the data for the colorPath: `colorPath.data([[0,percent,color]])`

The whole working example is right here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ox82vGxhcaoXJpVpUel1?p=preview

Comment: @OamPsy You're very welcome, please accept as the correct answer, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First give Id to the path like this:

```
var path = svg.selectAll("path")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("path")
                .style("fill", function(d){return d[2];})
                .attr("d", arc)
                .attr("id", function(d,i){return "id"+i;})//give id
```

Then inside the tween pass the condition and change the color of the path

```
.attrTween("d", function (a) {
                    var i  = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
                    var i2 = d3.interpolate(progress, percent)
                    this._current = i(0);

                    return function(t) {
                        if(i2(t) < 33.3)
                          d3.selectAll("#id1").style("fill", "red")
                        else if(i2(t) < 66.6)
                          d3.selectAll("#id1").style("fill", "orange")
                        else if(i2(t) > 66.6)
                          d3.selectAll("#id1").style("fill", "green")

                        text.text( format(i2(t) / 100) );
                        return arc(i(t));
                    };
                });
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/oMSAnJb6RE46dWmIqP94?p=preview)

**EDIT**

Inside your directive you can make `gradient` inside your `defs` like this:

```
        var defs = svg.append("defs");
        var gradient1 = defs.append("linearGradient").attr("id", "gradient1");
        gradient1.append("stop").attr("offset", "0%").attr("stop-color", "red");
        gradient1.append("stop").attr("offset", "25%").attr("stop-color", "orange");
        gradient1.append("stop").attr("offset", "75%").attr("stop-color", "green");
```

Then in the path you can define the gradient like this:

```
 var path = svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .style("fill", function(d, i) {
          if (i == 0) {
            return d[2];
          } else {
            return "url(#gradient1)";
          }
        })
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/5MxI7s3QeHIGLZmGA1QJ?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is really great! Highly appreciate the effort you've put in. Possibly i didnt make what im after clear enough, rather than the arc change the entire colour to either red/green/orange, i wanted a gradient effect, like here: https://www.google.co.uk/imgres?imgurl=https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/02/26/17/13/red-650676_960_720.png&imgrefurl=https://pixabay.com/en/red-yellow-green-orange-lime-650676/&h=644&w=960&tbnid=0L-m59MbMKaU5M:&docid=NN4MXwkocHBA2M&ei=m2GrVrXYHMvzUqu_ucgH&tbm=isch&ved=0ahUKEwj1kfqQic_KAhXLuRQKHatfDnkQMwhLKCQwJA

Comment: @OamPsy SVG doesn't do that though. You can have a linear gradient or a radial gradient, neither of which allow you to set a gradient along a shape. To get what you want you'd probably need to code it in canvas.

Comment: @RobertLongson - i see, thank you for the explanation. Ok, i guess i need a canvas then. I'll update title.

Comment: Only reason i thought it was possible becuase of this example http://codepen.io/sixsided/pen/ZYdZvG

Comment: @OamPsy That's a linear gradient, see how it's symmetrical about the x axis. Is that what you want?

Comment: @RobertLongson - yes, but using the colours and percentages mentioned above.

Comment: @OamPsy I have updated my answer check teh **EDIT** section with gradient as one shown in the example http://codepen.io/sixsided/pen/ZYdZvG you can change the stop percent as per your requirement.