# Create a crystal (or tile mosaic?) gradient background , presumably using canvas (or svg?)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

I want to programmatically create the following effect as the background of a div. Programmatically because I want the colors to be customizable. I'm not sure how to even get started thinking about this. I know several ways to add a gradient as a background color, but I'm not sure how to do the "mosaic blur" thing at all, so I'm looking for some direction or tools that might be useful.

[image: a 'crystal' or gradient tile mosaic background]

If there is a common name for that effect, please let me know so I can update the title and use it to ask Mr. Google how to get this done.

It looks like this is some kind of layer on top of a gradient, where the second layer magnifies or blunts or takes part of the color?

### not completely unrelated posts

[Angular svg or canvas to use colour gradients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065405/angular-svg-or-canvas-to-use-colour-gradients)

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: To me this looks like a bunch of semi-transparent layers on top of a static background color

Comment: `Requirements: ... Bonus points for ...` Deadline? Salary?

Comment: @Thomas - first, congratulations on getting that nickname. :)  Second, good point. I guess I just worded it the way I think about requirements. I'm happy to just have an idea of how to get it done. I'll reword.

Comment: If anyone has a suggestion about how I could update the title so anyone else looking for this could find it via Google, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fairly simple to do:

- Create a primary linear gradient as background
- Using blending mode `lighter` (AKA add) to add transparent white circles, lines, other patterns, on top at large sizes

The lighter mode is not strictly necessary but it gives a nice effect of the patterns being light sources.

### Conceptual demo

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

// background gradient
var gr = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,c.height);
gr.addColorStop(0, "#007");
gr.addColorStop(1, "#909");
ctx.fillStyle = gr;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

// Additive overlays
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,0.05)";
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
ctx.translate(c.width>>1, 0);  // move origin to center so we can mirror
for(var r = c.height, x; r > 20; r -= c.height/5) {
  x = Math.random() * c.width * 1.5
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, c.height, r, 0, 6.28);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.scale(-1,1);            // mirror, draw same on top
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, c.height, r, 0, 6.28);
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```html
<h3>Hit run again to create a new random pattern</h3>
<canvas id=c width=150 height=300></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to access the elements programmatically, you're going to want to use either SVGs or Canvas.

The images look like a series of transparent layers stacked over each other.
Look into using rgba for color. rgba is like rgb, but includes an alpha layer entered as a percentage at the end.

That being said, if you take the top left as an example. There may be gradients involved, but it looks like a solid pink background with transparent orange circles running off canvas on both sides.  As they continue to overlap, you get the gradient

It's a little small to tell.. but that would be a place to start. All the others are variations on the same theme.  Overlapping semi-transparent shapes.

If you are looking for a direct copy, start by sampling colors from two points where you think there is a gradient first.  It could be your eyes deceiving you.  The "gradient" you perceive may just be a solid color next to a dark and light area.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I can't "check" multiple answers!

Answer (score 1):

a quick scribble how this could be made with SVG.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 580 400" style="background: blue;">
 <g style="fill: rgba(255, 0, 0, .15);">
  <path d="m-39.5-42.80l679.5,372.80l3,127l-684-27" />
  <path d="m620.5,6.19l-661.5,296.80l10,141l647-15" />
  <path d="m-14.5,100.19l615.5,234.80l-5,95c0.5,0.20-616.5-10.79-616.5-10.79" />
  <path d="m597.5,98.19l-628.5,253.80l6,82l638-9" />
  <path d="m-25.5,201.19l639.5,181.80l-8,56l-629-18" />
  <path d="m606.5,224.19l-647.5,164.80l5,51l645-9" />
 </g>
</svg>
```

Sry about the quality, I'm on the wrong computer. I just made this quick example in an online SVG-editor *(plus some cleanup)*.

Add more layer, maybe give the layer slightly different colors/alpha-values; maybe add some curves, ... That's all up to you, to style this thing as you want.

But you get the basic idea on how to build the effect.

Comment: The other answer was actually "programatic" as I requested so I felt obligated to check that one. However, I ended up using this because I couldn't get canvas to work as a background. :)